# How do you draw a $K_{m.n}$ graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

$K_{3,3}$ is a complete bipartite graph with $6$ nodes split into $2$ groups of $3$ nodes. All of nodes in one group are connected to all of the nodes in the other groups, but not with nodes in the same group. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

However, what is a graph of $K_{m,n}$ supposed to look like? From my understanding the graph will have $m+n$ many nodes, $m$ nodes with a degree of $n$ and $n-m$ nodes with degree $n$. For example, $K_{2,3}$ looks like:

[image]

Is my understanding correct? If not, please explain how $K_{m,n}$ is supposed to look like.

Comment: In your description of what a $K_{m,n}$ graph is, you forgot one of the most important details... that the vertices are partitioned into two separate parts and no two vertices within the same part share an edge.  This leads to a simple way to picture $K_{m,n}$ as being a collection of $n$ vertices on the "left" and $m$ vertices on the "right" (*or top and down*) where edges exist between two vertices if *and only if* they are in different parts.

Comment: Your drawing of $K_{2,3}$, while correct, loses this feel for having *partitioned* the vertices.  It is nice in that the drawing is planar, but that isn't necessarily a concern.  Recall that graphs can have multiple equally valid *drawings*.  You could just have easily drawn the graph with two vertices on the left and three vertices on the right.  As a final aside, the first graph you picture is not $K_{3,3}$ but is instead $C_6$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is respectively what $K_{1,3}$, $K_{3,5}$ and $K_{4,8}$ look like.

[image]

In each graph, the two sets of the bipartition are on the left and on the right respectively.

Your $K_{2,3}$ graph is correct but not your $K_{3,3}$ since it misses $3$ edges.